# Error on Deserializing on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, deserialization

i'm trying deserializing this string: "`"{\"Id\":1,\"Ent\":\"TUROS\",\"Data\":\"2010-09-09\",\"Ap\":\"004510875954\",\"Mat\":\"1129\"}"`" to an object, but i catch this error:

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type Seguro. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

My code:

```
private void sendPostCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle result

        var status = e.Result;
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(status);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Seguro));
        Seguro car = (Seguro)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContractSerializer is to be used to deserialize xml. For Json you should use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (Just replace DataContractSerializer by DataContractJsonSerializer in your code and it should work)  or  [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) (which will give you a little more flexibility)

Comment: it's works DataContractJsonSerializer , i need add System.ServiceModel.Web.dll to my references :). thanks a lot.